# Terraform: Dynamic blocks with multiple conditional contents

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a module for the azure cdn frontdoor rule with a dynamic block:

Initially, this was how the module was:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main" {
  name                      = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_name
  cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_id = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_id
  order                     = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_order
  behavior_on_match         = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_behavior_on_match

  dynamic "conditions" {
    for_each = var.conditions_settings
    content {
      host_name_condition {
        operator         = conditions.value["host_name_operator"]
        negate_condition = conditions.value["host_name_negate_condition"]
        match_values     = conditions.value["host_name_match_values"]
        transforms       = conditions.value["host_name_transforms"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But right now I want to add other contents:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main" {
  name                      = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_name
  cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_id = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_id
  order                     = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_order
  behavior_on_match         = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_behavior_on_match

  dynamic "conditions" {
    for_each = var.conditions_settings
    content {
      host_name_condition {
        operator         = conditions.value["host_name_operator"]
        negate_condition = conditions.value["host_name_negate_condition"]
        match_values     = conditions.value["host_name_match_values"]
        transforms       = conditions.value["host_name_transforms"]
      }
      is_device_condition {
        operator         = conditions.value["is_device_operator"]
        negate_condition = conditions.value["is_device_negate_condition"]
        match_values     = conditions.value["is_device_match_values"]
      }
      post_args_condition {
        post_args_name = conditions.value["post_args_name"]
        operator       = conditions.value["post_args_operator"]
        match_values   = conditions.value["post_args_match_values"]
        transforms     = conditions.value["post_args_transforms"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run this I get the error below:

```
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with module.cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_spa_rule_1.azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule.main,
│   on ../../../modules/azure/cdn-frontdoor-rule/main.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main":
│    1: resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main" {
│ 
│ The argument "conditions.0.post_args_condition.0.post_args_name" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with module.cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_spa_rule_1.azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule.main,
│   on ../../../modules/azure/cdn-frontdoor-rule/main.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main":
│    1: resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main" {
│ 
│ The argument "conditions.0.post_args_condition.0.operator" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with module.cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_spa_rule_1.azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule.main,
│   on ../../../modules/azure/cdn-frontdoor-rule/main.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main":
│    1: resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main" {
│ 
│ The argument "conditions.0.url_filename_condition.0.operator" is required, but no definition was found.
```

I've also tried this:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main" {
  name                      = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_name
  cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_id = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_id
  order                     = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_order
  behavior_on_match         = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_behavior_on_match

  dynamic "conditions" {
    for_each = var.conditions_settings
    content {
      host_name_condition {
        operator         = conditions.value["host_name_operator"]
        negate_condition = conditions.value["host_name_negate_condition"]
        match_values     = conditions.value["host_name_match_values"]
        transforms       = conditions.value["host_name_transforms"]
      }
    }
    content {
      is_device_condition {
        operator         = conditions.value["is_device_operator"]
        negate_condition = conditions.value["is_device_negate_condition"]
        match_values     = conditions.value["is_device_match_values"]
      }
    }
    content {
      post_args_condition {
        post_args_name = conditions.value["post_args_name"]
        operator       = conditions.value["post_args_operator"]
        match_values   = conditions.value["post_args_match_values"]
        transforms     = conditions.value["post_args_transforms"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I also get the error below:

```
│ Error: Extraneous dynamic content block
│ 
│   on ../../../modules/azure/cdn-frontdoor-rule/main.tf line 50, in resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main":
│   50:     content {
│ 
│ Only one nested content block is allowed for each dynamic block.
```

How can I fix the dynamic block contents so that they are conditional, which will allow the contents to be selected conditionally?

Comment: You can't "fix" it. What you want is simply not supported.

Comment: Is there any work around or some other solution I could implement for this?

Answer (score 1):

From referring to [the documentation for this resource type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cdn_frontdoor_rule) it seems like it's possible to use any combination of condition type blocks in the `conditions` block, but if you include any specific block type then it's mandatory to populate certain arguments inside it.

With that structure in mind I would suggest to use a nested structure where your input variable reflects a similar hierarchy to that used by the resource type's configuration schema:

```
variable "conditions" {
  type = object({
    host_name = optional(set(object({
      operator         = string
      match_values     = optional(list(string))
      transforms       = optional(list(string))
      negate_condition = optional(bool)
    })), [])
    is_device = optional(set(object({
      operator         = string
      match_values     = optional(list(string))
      negate_condition = optional(bool)
    })), [])
  })
  default = {}
}
```

The above declaration calls for an object type with an attribute for each condition type, all of which are optional. When one isn't set Terraform will use an empty set as its default value. The default for the entire variable is an object with default values for all of the attributes, and so by default they will all be empty sets.

It isn't clear from the resource type documentation whether it's valid to have a `condition` block with no nested blocks inside of it at all. Just in case it isn't, you can derive a total count of all conditions of all types to use as the condition for whether to include a `conditions` block at all:

```
locals {
  total_conditions_count = sum([
    for s in var.conditions : length(s)
  ]...)
}
```

This uses [`sum`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/sum) with a [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) to first count the number of elements in each of the sets and then to add all of those together to find the total count. This value will therefore be zero if there are no conditions specified in `var.conditions`.

With those supporting declarations in place, you can then declare the resource itself:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "main" {
  name                      = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_name
  cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_id = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_id
  order                     = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_order
  behavior_on_match         = var.cdn_frontdoor_rule_behavior_on_match

  dynamic "conditions" {
    for_each = local.total_conditions_count > 0 ? [var.conditions] : []
    content {
      dynamic "host_name_condition" {
        for_each = conditions.value.host_name
        content {
          operator         = host_name_condition.value.operator
          negate_condition = host_name_condition.value.negate_condition
          match_values     = host_name_condition.value.match_values
          transforms       = host_name_condition.value.transforms
        }
      }
      dynamic "is_device_condition" {
        for_each = conditions.value.is_device
        content {
          operator         = is_device_condition.value.operator
          negate_condition = is_device_condition.value.negate_condition
          match_values     = is_device_condition.value.match_values
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This now uses two levels of `dynamic` block. The `dynamic "conditions"` block declares that there should only be a `conditions` block if there's at least one condition given in `var.conditions`. If that condition passes then each of the nested `dynamic` blocks generates zero or more blocks of each supported condition type. Importantly, if there are no conditions of a particular type then it will generate zero blocks of that type, thereby avoiding the error you encountered where certain arguments are required once a block is present.

When calling this module, your users would specify the conditions as a nested data structure. For example:

```
module "example" {
  source = "../example"

  conditions = {
    host_name = [
      {
        operator = "Equal"
        match_values = [
          "www.contoso.com",
          "images.contoso.com",
          "video.contoso.com",
        ]
        transforms = ["Lowercase", "Trim"]
      },
    ]
    is_device = [
      {
        operator     = "Equal"
        match_values = ["Mobile"]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

The key advantage of this nested structure is that the variable's type constraint reflects the same required and optional arguments as the underlying resource type, and so the type constraint ensures that the user input will always be valid for the resource type, including generating a similar error as you saw inside the module if someone forgets to set `operator` when they are defining a condition when calling the module.